# ESXi 6.7 Instant Clone without vCenter

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, powercli

Is it possible to create an Instant Clone of a Virtual Machine in VMware ESXi 6.7 Standard without a vCenter Server present using PowerCLI?

Answer (score 5):

No.

Turns out you can't have a three-character answer on this site :)

Comment: Is it possible with vSphere Essentials or Essentials Plus?

Comment: Either option gives you vCenter, and it's vCenter you need to create and delete Instant Clones - even then there's no GUI option right now, you need to use the MOB method to do this. Edit - I forgot that there are PowerCLI cmdlets for this too (https://labs.vmware.com/flings/powercli-extensions)

Comment: So vMotion isn't a requirement?

Comment: No not at all - unless you want to move them of course :)